# How Sticky Message Will Automatically Close After 10seconds

Tags: jquery, css, hover

Well, I know how to show closeable sticky message, but I wana know how do I make it close after 10seconds, and show the 10seconds counter... and how do I give it hover effect as well...
Here is my closeable sticky message, just for ur kind consideration

```
<script>
function closeBox(toClose) {
    document.getElementById(toClose).style.display = "none";setCookie(toClose,closed", 20);}

function setCookie(cName, value, expiredays) {var expDate = new Date();expDate.setDate(expDate.getDate()+expiredays);document.cookie=cName + "=" + escape(value) + ";expires=" + expDate.toGMTString();}

    function loadMsg(msgClass) {msg = document.getElementsByTagName("div");for (i=0; i<msg.length; i++){if(msg[i].className == msgClass) {if(document.cookie.indexOf(msg[i].id) == -1) {msg[i].style.display = "block";}}}}

    window.onload=function(){loadMsg('msgbox'); }
</script>

    http://kownleg.blogspot.com
    <style>
    div.guestwarn {
    background:#000000;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    max-width:280px;min-height:18px;padding:0 5px 3px;position:fixed;right: 2%;
        top: 50%;padding: 10px 15px;position: fixed;z-index: 10;font-size:12px;-moz-border-radius: 8px; -webkit-border-radius: 8px;  filter:alpha(opacity=88);
        -moz-opacity:.88; opacity:.88; -moz-box-shadow:5px 5px 5px #191919; -webkit-box-shadow:5px 5px 5px #191919; box-shadow:5px 5px 5px #191919;
    }
    .close {float: right;background: transparent url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-hMdL9UJje_c/UA7nJADBTSI/AAAAAAAAABU/S5zftNPRxfs/s1600/close.png);width: 22px;height: 22px;}
     </style> 


 <div id="message-1" class="msgbox" style="display: none;">
    <div class="guestwarn"><a href="#" class="close" onclick="closeBox('message-1');   return false;" title=""></a>
**My Sticky Text Is Here**
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You'll need to use `setTimeout`

Comment: You can simply perform this using jquery `delay()` function .See the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line at the end of the script:

```
setTimeout(function(){closeBox('message-1')}, 10000);
```

Comment: wow, its working... but I think in my coding, I made some mistake, when someone close this message, it will never come on refresh.. I wana make it like, when someone close it or not, but next he visit the site again, it always show to them, but if someone close it, it will close temporary not permanently.. can u pls help me??

Answer (score 1):

There are already many plugins built for this, I prefer [Purr](http://kitchen.net-perspective.com/open-source/purr/), another one I know of is [jQuery Growl](http://www.fragmentedcode.com/jquery-growl/).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply perform this using jquery `delay()` function.

```
$("#message-1").live("click",function(){
        $(".guestwarn").show('slow');
        // show the counter
         $(".guestwarn").delay(10000).hide("slow");
          return false;
        });
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply, but this works perfect... **setTimeout(function(){closeBox('message-1')}, 10000);**

Comment: @RJStyle Try this it will also solve your problem of temporary showing of box